# RawInput : not handle Keyboard Event on condition

Tags: c#, raw-input

I try to use this project :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

I want to handle keys just for a specific keyboard.

It is working but, I want to release event and run the default code for the other keyboards... How can I do that ?

Here the code :

```
  var rawinput = new RawInput(Handle, CaptureOnlyInForeground);
   // Adding a message filter will cause keypresses to be handled
  rawinput.AddMessageFilter();   
  rawinput.KeyPressed += OnKeyPressed;

private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, RawInputEventArg e)
{
  if (e.KeyPressEvent.DeviceName == "My Device")
  {
    // I handle the event et run my custom code
  }
  else
  {
    // I don't want to handle the event and run default processing (fill textbox, etc.)
    // How can I do ?
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try simply ```break;``` from it?

Comment: or if ```break``` doesn't work in event handlers, than maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522504/how-to-break-event-handler) suits your needs?